# How to return image/png media type response in Spray?

Tags: spray

I want to return `image/PNG` as response to calling URL. How can I do it in Spray?

Answer (score 4):

This may help:

```
import java.io._
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._

sender ! HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(`image/png`, HttpData(new File("my.png"))))
```

See also, [HttpMessage](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.2/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpMessage.scala), [HttpEntity](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpEntity.scala), [HttpData](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/HttpData.scala) and [MediaTypes](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/release/1.2/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/MediaType.scala). You can do same for `HttpRequest` as well. You can use `Array[Byte]` or `ByteString` instead of `File`. Checked for *Spray 1.3.x*.