# Where to put favicon for a scala Spray application (i.e. what is the root of the site?)?

Tags: scala, rest, akka, favicon, spray

Internet says I should put my favicon.ico in the root of the site to stop Spray from clogging my logs with huge stacktraces.  I don't know what the root of the site means, particularly in the context of a RESTful spray application.

Suppose my project is in ~/src/my-project - I build it (`sbt assembly`), and run it from this location, where should I put the favicon.ico??  I tried putting in ~/src/my-project but I still get the stacktrace.

NB: it only throws the exception if I directly access the API from my browser (rather than via the actual front end of our website).

Comment: Maybe you should also add the respective route, like [`path("favicon.ico"){getFromResource("favicon.ico")}`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/file-and-resource-directives/getFromResource/)

Comment: @dk14 That seems logical, I'll give it a try. Your comment is worthy of being an answer no?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most current browsers are automatically looking for [`favicon.ico`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon) inside your site's root. So, you have to process their `GET /favicon.ico` [http-requests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods). The easiest way to do that is to use [`spray-routing`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing)'s [`getFromResource`](http://spray.io/documentation/1.1-SNAPSHOT/spray-routing/file-and-resource-directives/getFromResource/):

```
import spray.routing.SimpleRoutingApp
import spray.http._
import MediaTypes._

object Main extends App with SimpleRoutingApp {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("my-system")

  startServer(interface = "localhost", port = 8080) {
    path("favicon.ico") {
      getFromResource("favicon.ico", `image/x-icon`) // will look for the file inside your `resources` folder
    }
  }
}
```

If you already have some processing actor (and don't use `spray-routing`), you will need to process `GET /favicon.ico` directly inside your actor, returning something like:

```
def receive = {
   case HttpRequest(GET, Uri.Path("/favicon.ico"), _, _, _) => 
      sender ! HttpResponse(entity = HttpEntity(`image/x-icon`, 
         HttpData(new File("favicon.ico")))) //will take it from a file in application folder, you may also pass any array of byte instead of File
   ...
}
```

See [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28128200/1809978) for more info about second option.

P.S. If you don't want to bother with `favicon.ico` file - you may return just `StatusCodes.NotFound` in both cases:

- `complete(NotFound)` for routing
- `sender ! HttpResponse(NotFound)` for your own actor

As it's done inside [`SiteServiceActor`](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/site/src/main/scala/spray/site/SiteServiceActor.scala).

Also, using [W3C's preferred method](http://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon) (putting the link inside your web pages) won't guarantee cross-browser compatibility as it depends on the browser's search order and there is no W3C standard about that (see [siteData-36](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/issues.html?type=1#siteData-36)). Most browsers seems to look inside the site's root first, even if you don't have any html pages.

Comment: There should really be a built-in route for this, say `favicon`.